# How to add a view with contextual filters in a panel

Tags: views

I created a view with some contextual filter and relationships. When i add this view to a menu tab from a node, the view is working ok.
But when i add this view to a panel, it gives me the message that there are no items added yet (my own custom text when the view is empty).

Like it should be:
[image]

And how it is through panes:

[image]

Can somebody help me with this? Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

I added %1 to arguments and it seems to be working now. But can someone explain what this is exactly? I don't really understand why its working with this.